# Phonebook using a trie

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, complexity, trie

I implemented a PhoneBook utilizing a `Trie` data structure.

Could I ask you to evaluate it?

Did I apply `Trie` correctly for such case or is it better to store data somehow else?

I'm looking not only for working solution but also for an optimal one in terms of run-time and storage.

From my calculations, it takes NlogT to `add()` and `get()` where N is a number of chars and T is a number of children.

Am I right?

Here is the logic

```
public final class PhoneBook {

    private final Node name;

    private final Node surname;

    private final Comparator<Record> comparator;

    public PhoneBook() {
        this.name = new Node();
        this.surname = new Node();
        comparator = (r1, r2) -> {
            int result = r1.getName().compareTo(r2.getName());
            if (result == 0) {
                result = r1.getSurname().compareTo(r2.getSurname());
                if (result == 0) {
                    result = r1.getNumber().compareTo(r2.getNumber());
                }
            }
            return result;
        };
    }

    public void add(final Record record) {
        add(record.getName().toLowerCase(), record, name);
        add(record.getSurname().toLowerCase(), record, surname);
    }

    public SortedSet<Record> get(final String prefix) {
        final String lc = prefix.toLowerCase();
        final List<Record> recordsRetrievedByName = get(lc, name);
        final List<Record> recordsRetrievedBySurname = get(lc, surname);
        final SortedSet<Record> result = new TreeSet<>(comparator);
        result.addAll(recordsRetrievedByName);
        result.addAll(recordsRetrievedBySurname);
        return result;
    }

    private List<Record> get(final String prefix, final Node ancestor) {
        Node node = ancestor;
        for (final char c: prefix.toCharArray()) {
            final Node child = node.children.get(c);
            if (child == null) {
                return Collections.emptyList();
            }
            node = child;
        }
        return node.records;
    }

    private void add(final String str, final Record record, final Node ancestor) {
        Node node = ancestor;
        for (final char c: str.toCharArray()) {
            final Node child;
            if (node.children.containsKey(c)) {
                child = node.children.get(c);
            } else {
                child = new Node();
                node.children.put(c, child);
            }
            child.records.add(record);
            node = child;
        }
    }

    private static final class Node {

        private final Map<Character, Node> children = new TreeMap<>();

        private final List<Record> records = new ArrayList<>();

    }

}
```

And the `Record` immutable object

```
public final class Record {

    private final String name;

    private final String surname;

    private final String number;

    //constructor, getters, toString
}
```

Comment: It's look fine. I am also a beginner so i don't have very good knowledge about it. So i suggest to you please check this link for more https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/trie-insert-and-search/

Answer (score 2):

### Naming:

`name` and `surname` are somewhat unclear in what they specifically mean. The "actual" purpose of these variables is to serve as "root" of the trie. Incidentally I'd rename `ancestor` to `root`in all the usages in your code, simply because I'm more used to it. YMMV :)
I'd rename `name` and `surname` to `nameRoot` and `surnameRoot`.

### Simplifications:

- Initialize private fields that are not dependent on constructor arguments in the field declaration to save on space and complexity.
- Use `Comparator.comparing` and `thenComparing` to simplify your comparator.

I personally also prefer to not leave too much space between fields.

```java
private final Node name = new Node();
private final Node surname = new Node();
private static final Comparator<Record> comparator = Comparator.comparing(Record::getName)
    .thenComparing(Record::getSurname).thenComparing(Record::getNumber);
```

Note that I also changed the `comparator` to be static. It could also do with a better name, but I'm coming up empty right now...

### Possible Trie Optimizations:

Currently your trie is using a **lot** of memory. It's not quite as bad as it could be, but considering that names are very much non-uniform, you will have a lot of "degenerated branches", where the branching factor is very low, if not 1 for "long" stretches of the data structure.

These long stretches of basically linked lists can be collapsed by sacrificing a WORD of memory to store how many characters you can skip before the next *actual* branching.

Currently `Node` does not support this in any way.

---

The traversal during `add` can be simplified a bit with `computeIfAbsent` like so:

```java
for (final char c: str.toCharArray()) {
    final Node child = node.children.computeIfAbsent(c, Node::new);
    child.records.add(record);
    node = child;
}
```

This simplification pretty quickly vanishes when you implement the optimization mentioned above (or rather it becomes somewhat complicated).

Comment: Hi, thank you for such a great response. Could I ask if you can extend a part about Trie memory optimization?

Comment: That kind of goes beyond what I want to put into an answer, but you should be able to find some useful information using the search term "Patricia-Trie"